# If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of a group $G$, is their product also a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for $AB = \{ab|\;a\in A, \; b\in B\}$ to be a subgroup of a group $G$, given $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$? Is it even a *subset* of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe he/she means $AB$ and not $A\times B$.

Comment: @Gregory: That’s certainly very possible, maybe even probably, but the question does need clarification.

Comment: The statement in the title is true when one of the subgroups is normal.

Comment: I meant the product.

Comment: Why do you tag your questions with set theory tags? They have nothing to do with set theory!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. Consider the subgroups of $S_4$ given by:

$A = \{e, (1\ 4)\}, B = \{e, (1\ 2 \ 3), (1\ 3\ 2)\}$.

Then $AB = \{e, (1\ 4), (1\ 2\ 3), (1\ 3\ 2), (1\ 2\ 3\ 4), (1\ 3\ 2\ 4)\}$

which isn't closed under multiplication:

$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4) = (1\ 3)(2\ 4) \not\in AB$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e\in AB$. Let $x\in AB$ then $x=ab$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then $x^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}\in BA$ which is generally not equal to $AB$. So inverse of every element in $AB$ may not exist in $AB$ for which $AB$ is not a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

$H, N < G$ subgroups and $H \unlhd G$ normal subgroup, then $HN=\{hn : h \in H, n \in n \}$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since if $hn , h_1n_1 \in HN$ then $hn ( h_1n_1)^{-1}=hn n_1^{-1} h_1^{-1} = h ( n n_1^{-1} h _1^{-1} (n n_1^{-1})^{-1}) (n n_1^{-1})$ and since $ H \unlhd G$, $( n n_1^{-1} h _1^{-1} (n n_1^{-1})^{-1}) \in H$, hence $hn ( h_1n_1)^{-1} \in HN$, proving that $HN$ is a subgroup.

But if you are talking about $H \times N$ then it is not a subset of $G$ hence it cannot be a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Given $A, \ B \le G$
$AB=\{ab \ | \ a \in A, \ b \in B \} \le G \iff AB = BA$

$(\implies) \ AB \le G \implies \forall \ ab \in AB, (ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1} \in AB$ 
$A, B \le G \implies a^{-1} \in A, \ b^{-1} \in B \implies (ab)^{-1} \ \in BA \implies AB \subseteq BA$
$\forall \ ba \in BA, ba = (ab)^{-1} \implies \forall \ ba \in BA, \  ba \in AB \implies BA \subseteq AB$
$AB \subseteq BA, \ BA \subseteq AB \implies AB = BA$

$(\impliedby)$ We use the 2-step subgroup test. We must show that $AB$ has closure and inverses.

$AB = BA \implies \{ab| \ a \in A, \ b \in B \} = \{ba| \ b \in B, \ a \in A \}$

Consider $ab \in AB; \ (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}; \  A, \ B \le G \implies a^{-1} \in A, \ b^{-1} \in B \implies b^{-1}a^{-1} \in BA = AB$
Thus, $\forall \ ab \in AB, \ (ab)^{-1} \in AB$, and the inverse condition of the 2-step subgroup test is met.

$Lemma:$ Since $AB=BA, \ \forall ab \in AB \ \exists \ b'a' \in BA$ such that $ab=b'a'$

Now consider $a_1b_1, \ a_2b_2 \in AB$.
$(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)=a_1(b_1a_2)b_2)=a_1a_3b_3b_1$ by the above lemma;
$a_1a_3b_3b_1=(a_1a_3)(b_3b_1)=ab\in AB$ since $a\in A, \ b\in B$

With conditions 1 and 2 of the 2-step subgroup test, we have $AB \le G. \;\mathbf{QED}$

As previous comments and answers have noted, if either $A$ or $B$ is a normal subgroup, then $AB \le G$. If either subgroup is normal, then the above condition is met.

Since all subgroups of an Abelian Group are normal, this product is always a subgroup in Abelian Groups.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=S_3$, $A=\langle(1,2)\rangle$, $B=\langle(2,3)\rangle$. Then
$$AB=\{e,(1,2),(2,3),(1,3,2)\}$$

Note that the inverse of $(1,3,2)$, that is, $(1,2,3)$ is not in $AB$. So, $AB$ is not in general a subgroup.

It is, nevertheless, if $G$ is abelian.